# How to find if an item in a Windows folder is really hidden from the user?

Tags: .net, windows, directory, explorer, file-attributes

I need to get the count of items (folders and files) in a Windows folder. I can easily do it based on the condition if I should include hidden items or not. But in my program I want to get the count of items that is visible to the user! i.e. if hidden items are visually visible in the folder, then it should be included in the count. If hidden items are not visible, then it shouldnt be included.

So how can I know if "show hidden files" property is set on Windows machine. In other words is there a way I can find if a file or directory is "really hidden" (visually) from the user??

## Update: **I am going to re-open this question. Though the original answers here answered my question, to a certain extent its not foolproof.**

Here is the new scenario:

Certain files in C drive (not anywhere else yet), are *visually hidden*, though their hidden attribute is false (or unchecked), **strangely**. Those files look pale like other hidden files when made visible (from folder options) and they get *visually hidden* when we set "do not show hidden files" in folder options (like any other normal hidden file).

Those files in my machine as I see are `autoexec.bat` and `config.sys` in `C:\`. I found this on a Windows XP machine and as well as a Windows 7 machine. Is there a way to identify such files? Basically I was trying to get the count of visible(visually) files in a directory, and my application fails when it attempts to get count of files in `C:\`. What happens is that the application counts those two files (since its attribute is not hidden), but from a visual standpoint, they are hidden normally, like this:

```
string[] f = Directory.GetFiles(path);

int count = 0;
foreach (string s in f)
{
    FileInfo i = new FileInfo(s);
    if ((i.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0)
        count++;
}

return count;
```

So I think the only correct way is calling the Shell API. I am looking for a good starter..

Thanks..

Comment: The way to do this is by asking the shell, "Hey, what items are you going to show to the user?" instead of trying to replicate the shell algorithm. Bind to the directory and call IShellFolder::EnumObjects.

Comment: @RaymondChen Could you get me a link to the right destination? Not that I cant find myself, but it cant be as good as one you fetch..

Comment: You have a number of options, but maybe the easiest is to create an IShellItem and then ask for BHID_EnumItems. Or you could do it the classical way with SHParseDisplayName, SHGetDesktopFolder, IShellFolder::BindToObject and then IShellFolder::EnumObjects.

Answer (score 2):

There is a registry key to check for the global flag regarding "showing hidden files" at `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Hidden` - see http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/1007/

Edit:
Beware that there is another setting regarding "show system files" called `ShowSuperHidden`

Comment: you are welcome - beware that there is another setting regarding "show system files" called `ShowSuperHidden`...

Comment: oh is that System folders and files which we have to make it visible by selecting another option in folder options?Hope you got me

Comment: I have added a section to your answer so that it makes the answer perfect. pls approve :)

Comment: what happens if this registry key changes in a different version of windows? Are there implications with registry redirection?

Comment: @David Hefferman that is a very good question... although the OP specifically wants the setting of Windows (Explorer) - even without another Windows version, if the user uses a different file manager then this setting could be meaninglesss...

Comment: I suspect that this could be handled without a registry hack by using the Shell API.

Comment: that might be but using Shell API would mean to change the codebase significantly for the OP... from what I gather the registry didn't change in this regard from Windos XP up to Windows 7 which is a very long time...

Comment: @Yahia I am unaccepting this answer and starting a bounty, as the registry method has some glitches.

Comment: @nawfal what describe as "glitches" is a different thing altogether - it seems you mean "system files"...

Comment: @Yahia they (those two files) could be system files, but they are unlike normal system files. I mean Normal system files have their hidden attribute set to true (in a read only manner), hence combined with your registry method and normal attribute checking via .net, I can know if they are really hidden or not. but these two files have hidden attribute false, but still are really hidden. So our logic fails.. Shell API is the only method :(

Comment: @nawfal system files can be hidden by themselves - without the hidden attribute set...

Comment: @Yahia thats strange, but I did check their attribute via .net and command prompt, and no they are not system files. further more, all the system files (as far i learned) will have their hidden attribute set in a read only manner, but these two files are different, I mean their hidden attribute can be changed by users..

Answer (score 2):

This setting is stored in the registry, it is located:

```
User Key: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\
Advanced]
Value Name: Hidden
Data Type: REG_DWORD (DWORD Value)
Value Data: (1 = show hidden, 2 = do not show)
```

The code to access this value:

```
int hiddenValue = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\","Hidden",2);

if(hiddenValue == 1)
{
   //Files not hidden
}
else
{
   //Files are hidden
}
```

[Registry Key Details](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/1007/)

Answer (score 0):

`autoexec.bat` and `config.sys` in C:\  are system files which mention by Yahia, the  `ShowSuperHidden` setting.

Here is how you can check whether the file is system files or not. When the file attributes is HSA, it means Hidden, System & Files ready for archiving. 
Below are the list for file attributes.

```
File attributes: 

A = Files ready for archiving 

H = Hidden 

C = Compressed 

HC is two attributes = Hidden & Compressed 

R = Read-only 

S = System 

HSA is three attributes = Hidden, System & Files ready for archiving 

E = Encrypted 

Encrypted files and folders cannot be compressed.
```

Sources : http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/115561-45-file-attribute